# Prove that $ x^2+y^2\le1 $ from $x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta)\le1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm told that:
$$x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta)\le1,\quad ∀ \theta: 0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}, \quad x, y\ge 0 $$

and I'm asked to prove:
$$x^2+y^2≤1.$$

I square both sides and get
$$x^2\cos^2(\theta)+2xy\sin(\theta)\cos⁡(\theta)+y^2\sin^2(\theta)\le1,$$
and can show :
$$
\begin{align}
&x^2\cos^2(\theta)+2xy\sin(\theta)\cos⁡(\theta)+y^2\sin^2(\theta)\\
\le \ & x^2\cos^2(\theta)+y^2\sin^2(\theta)+x^2\sin^2 (\theta) +y^2\cos^2(\theta) \\
= \ & x^2+y^2 
\end{align}
$$
by $(x\sin(θ)-y\cos(θ))^2\ge0$ and $\cos^2 (\theta)+\sin^2 (\theta)=1$, but this only shows $$x^2+y^2\ge x^2\cos^2(\theta)+2xy\sin(\theta)\cos⁡(\theta)+y^2 \sin^2(\theta)\le1.$$
$$
i.e. x^2+y^2\ge \le 1
$$
instead of $$ x^2+y^2\le 1 $$
How do you prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Let the point $(x,y)$ be $(r,\theta)$ in polar coordinates. Then-

$$x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$$

Therefore
$$x\cos\theta +y\sin\theta = r\cos^2\theta + r\sin^2\theta = r \leq 1$$

But since $x^2+y^2 = r^2$,

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq1$$
Or
$$x^2+y^2\leq1$$
Note that we can make these substitutions only if $x,y\geq 0$ as $xy\leq 0$ wouldn't allow the intial substitution and $x,y\leq0$ would imply $r\leq 0$ which contradicts $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

By complex numbers, we can proceed as follows by

- $z=x-iy=|z|e^{i\alpha}$ with $\alpha \in \left[-\frac \pi 2,0\right]$
- $w=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)=e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta \in \left[0,\frac \pi 2\right]$

then we have

$$\Re(zw)=\Re(|z|e^{i(\alpha+\theta)})=x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta)=|z|\cos(\alpha+\theta) \le 1 \implies |z|=x^2+y^2\le 1$$

indeed $(\alpha + \theta) \in \left[-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2\right]\implies 0\le \cos(\alpha+\theta)\le 1$.